# Number of observations in a group as a new variable in existing dataset

Tags: r

I have data with groups and need to enumerate how many members are in each group as a new variable within the existing dataframe for the purpose of subsequently sub-setting the data for further analysis. I have gotten as far as enumerating each unique case within groups:

```
set.seed(42)
id <- sample(c(1:4), 10, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(id)

df$test1 <- ave(df$id,df$id, FUN=seq_along)
```

However, I would imagine some form of `by`, `aggregate`, `unique`, `dplyr`'s `count` or other solution would be invoked next, but none of these have been successful. I tried a few and viewed numerous posts that don't quite address the question or whose solutions fell short. Other posters frequently wanted to extract the the number of members as a table or vector (easily done with `table`, but I need the group member numbers to stay associated with the original data to arrive at the desired result. The next step in my specific problem is to subset based on the number of members in each group. The final result would ideally create the following data:

```
set.seed(42)
id <- sample(c(1:4), 10, replace=T)
group_N <- c(3,3,1,3,5,5,5,1,5,5) 
df <- data.frame(id, group_N)
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to stay in base R, repeat your code with `ave` and use `length` instead of `seq_along` as the `FUN` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R

```
df$group_size <- ave(df$id,df$id, FUN=length)
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(group_size = n())
```

Answer (score 1):

The data.table way.

```
set.seed(42)
id <- sample(c(1:4), 10, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(id)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, gs:=lapply(.SD, length), by="id"]
dt
#    id gs
# 1:  4  3
# 2:  4  3
# 3:  2  1
# 4:  4  3
# 5:  3  5
# 6:  3  5
# 7:  3  5
# 8:  1  1
# 9:  3  5
#10:  3  5
```